# How do I instantiate multiple instances of a background picture in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml

Okay, so basically when I click the below buttons I want a new separate pic to show where I specify.  That way I can have multiple copies of this pic in different locations on the page at any given time.  Help?!

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/formstyle.css"/> 
  <script type = "text/javascript" src = "scripts/rearange.js">

    var count = 0;

      function northwest(image) {

        var temp;
   var myElement;
        var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        newDiv.id = "image"+ count++;
   document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
   temp = newDiv.getAttribute("id") ;

   myElement = document.getElementById(temp).style;

        myElement.top = "30px";
        myElement.left = "340px";          }         

      function southeast(image) { 
        var myElement;//create reference
        myElement = document.getElementById('image').style;
        myElement.top = "338px";
        myElement.left = "667px";
     }

     function toggle(image) {
       var dom = document.getElementById(image);

       if (dom.style.display == '')
    dom.style.display = 'none';
   else
    dom.style.display = '';

  </script>

  <title>Exercise IV</title>

</head>

<body>  
    <div id = "para">
    Blah, Blah, Blah, Blah :)     
    </div>

    div id ="image" ></div>

    <div id = "links">
       <p style="height: 121px; width: 92px" >
          <input type="button" value = "northwest" onclick = "javascript: northwest('image')" />            
      <input type="button" value = "northeast" onclick = "javascript: northeast('image')" />            
      <input type="button" value = "southwest" onclick = "javascript: southwest('image')" />            
      <input type="button" value = "southeast" onclick = "javascript: southeast('image')" />

       </p>   
   </div>
   <div id = "show_Hide">
      <p style="width: 92px">
         &nbsp;<input type="button" value = "show/hide" onclick = "toggle('image')" />
         <input type="button" value = "show/hide" onclick = "toggle('image')" />
         <input type="button" value = "show/hide" onclick = "toggle('image')" /><input type="button" value = "show/hide" onclick = "toggle('image')" />
      </p>
   </div>

   <div id = "link" >    
      <p style="height: 14px; width: 180px">       
        <a href = "http://nova.umuc.edu/~ct386a28/lovej2ee/index.html">Home Page</a>
      </p>
   </div>
```

```
   /*********************************CSS*******************************************/
   #image {
     background-image:url('http://nova.umuc.edu/~ct386a28/lovej2ee/exercise4/images /kito.jpg');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;                                                                                 
 position: absolute; 
 top: 199px; 
     left: 513px; 
     color: inherit;
     width: 133px;
     height: 107px;
     filter:alpha(opacity=60);
     opacity:0.6;          
     } 

     #para {
     text-align: left;
     font-family: Arial;
     position: relative; 
     top: 73px; 
     left: 504px; 
     color: inherit;
     width: 132px;
     height: 341px;
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have two images, you need two `img` elements. Either start by having two of them in the document (not very flexible), or take a look at `document.createElement('img')` in JavaScript docs.

EDIT: sorry, you said background images. Same thing applies, just create more DIVs. You will have to change your CSS selector to something that is not ID (since IDs should be unique), so... make it a class.

```
.image { /* instead of #image */
  /* all that stuff */
}
```

and `<div class="image">` in HTML. In JS, you can do:

```
var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
newDiv.className = 'image';
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Amadan.  When I tried the changing to the class structure, the rest of my script stopped working (because it was all set to run with id's).  So I switched it back.  However,using the createElement() idea that you mentioned, I tried to use it to work with id's.  Take a look at my function code for northeast, any idea why that wouldnt show on my web page. I revised it with the most recent above.  Your thoughts are greatly appreciate!

Comment: I can't even tell what it's supposed to do. It's a mess :) But first of all, if you have IDs like image0, image1..., there's no way you can assign them a CSS (and thus, no background image). Therefore, use the class. You can use it in parallel with IDs, or you can go and change the rest of the script. Another thing is, there's a lot of voodoo programming going on: e.g. almost everything from `var newDiv` to `myElement`. You already have the ID (you just generated it), why extract it again with getAttribute? You already have the element (newDiv), why search for it with `getElementById`?

Comment: Well I figured this one out.  I just went ahead and placed multiple divs on the web page and used css to set them up. Then I used javascript to toggle them off and on. Not the prettiest script in the world, but it got the job done.  Thanks for your help Amadan.